# Animation Nodes - instance objects over time

Tags: animation-nodes, loop

I am trying to create an animation where torus's emanate from a centre at regular intervals (like the RKO Pictures radio wave animation). 
This means creating new instances over time.
I have managed to create expanding instances of a bezier curve, which is sort of the effect, but not really.
[image: circles scaling over time]
What I am looking to do is loop the expansion of a master circle over time.
Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The wave/scale effect is controlled by the scale of an empty (simply animate it the way you want).

The node setting is in two parts:

- Main part:

Get empty scale and generate a set of scales from it. 
Duplicates the model (a curve).
Put the result in the resulting curve.

[image]

The scale is limited between 1 and 5 in this setup but you can change it as you want.

The next nodes are making an array of scale.
Say current scale is 3.19, we want the array to be [1.19, 2.19, 3.19].
This is done using the float range node.

- Sub loop:

The loop is done over the precalculated scales (above).
For each scale duplicates the input vertices and scale them.
The result is merged (reassign to the output).

[image]

The result is cumulated in a "reassign" node which is also set as output.
The model input is set as copy as we want a new circle at each iteration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lemon. That is just what I am looking for. It is going to take me sometime to understand how you got there as I am a real newbie. Many thanks again. Christopher

Comment: I have found that when I try to add rings and space the distance between rings, the system breaks. Therefore, I have found that having the same integer number in the 2 maths nodes after the vector separate node and the Float Range node, solves the problem.

Comment: @ChristopherLowden, I've considered that the distance between ring can simply be changed changing the size (in edit mode) of the model curve (or you could also do than within nodes).

Comment: Edit mode works for me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The floor division of the scale of the master circle with some parameter controlling the density of the circles gives you the amount of the circles. You can use this amount in a *Float Range* node to get a list of scales for your circles, you can then use to do the replication:

[image: Node Tree]

Alternatively, you can use a start-end sequence to make the circles appear in the center:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you Omar. A very interesting way of doing it. The problem is that the replication adds at the outside of the circle and not the centre. I am really looking for a water ripple animation. So it has the same issue as the node set I did.

Comment: @ChristopherLowden I can't really imagine what you are saying. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In your version, every new instance is added to the outer edge of the circles at it grows. What I am looking for is a ripple where the each new instance starts in the centre.

Comment: @ChristopherLowden Added another method to the answer.